# "each" ... "do" returns an array when used in a helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I had this in my view layer:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs col-md-10 col-xs-12"> -->
        <% @months.each do |month| %>
          <%= content_tag :li do %>
            <%= content_tag :span, nil, class: "underlayer" %>
            <%= link_to ... %>

          <% end %>  
        <% end %>
</ul>
```

`@months` is a simple array of month names I have in my controller.

I decided to refactor this code and put all the view logic into a helper method. So I started:

show.html.erb:

```
<%= show_calendar %>
```

helper:

```
def show_calendar
  months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
end
```

I can't figure out why this keeps happening: when I try to perform `each` on an array:

```
months.each do |month|
  month
end
```

the return is always an array, instead of individual months. If I am to return a `content_tag` like this:

```
content_tag :span, month
```

it will return:

```
["<span>Jan</span>", ... ]
```

I figured I could use `collect` with a `concat` tag, but that is *not* what I'm looking for in this particular situation, because I have a complex link logic afterwards, which does not seem to work with `concat` in the long run.

What I would like to return in the end should look like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs col-md-10 col-xs-12">
        <li><span class="underlayer"></span><a href="#">Jan</a></li>
        <li><span class="underlayer"></span><a href="#">Feb</a></li>
...
</ul>
```

I would be thankful for any explanation of the `each`..`do` behaviour.

Comment: That's the way `each` method works - it returns the object the method was called on. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: where is the `months.each do |month|` code?  in the helper?

Comment: @MarekLipka updated question, and yes the each..do is in the helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Marek** mentioned in comments `each` do what it should do. You might want your method be like this:

```
def show_calendar
  months = %w(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec)

  ul_body = months.map { |month| custom_tag(string) }
  safe_join(ul_body, "<br />")
end

private

def custom_tag(string)
  %(<li><span class="underlayer"></span><a href="#"> #{string} </a></li>)
end
```

Comment: This won't work as desired as the `.join` at the end removes the `html_safe` flag of the strings and thus returns a string containing escaped HTML. You might want to use [safe_join](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper:safe_join) instead.

Comment: safe_join actually throws an error, while simple join returns array values as strings with tags shown; safe join should be rewritten like this: safe_join(ul_body)

Comment: So far this is the most elegant and closest solution, however I also need a way to add span tags additionally into my LIs (see original question)

Comment: @DenisG sorry, I am not railsist. And I am pretty sure that Rails provides us an appropriate method. But see the edit. That's how i'd do that.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as being the closest and most elegant, and I have to add that in order for the output code to fully answer my demand I have used string concatenation which looks like this:     ul_body = months.map do |month| 
      content_tag :li do
        link_to(month, "...") + 
        content_tag("span", nil, class: "...")
      end 
    end

Comment: Thanks @anonymous_downvoter for improving my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Each tag returns the array, not the block within it.

Something like this should work:

```
def show_calendar
  months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
  html = ""
  months.each do |month|
    html << content_tag :span, month # or any other tags/logic
  end

  html #return the calendar, not the month array
end
```

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: Won't this just return a concatted string?

Comment: yes, a html string. `<span>Jan</span><span>Feb</span>...` that's the idea of helpers